# Android App-side/Server-side validation or just App-side validation?

Tags: android

I am now developing my android app and Im looking at my server-side registration form validation, thinking - I would never send this request if the user hasnt provided a user name, email, password, etc so why am I validating for it?

I read lots of arguments on the internet about client/server side validation vs client-side-only validation and all of the arguments against client-side-only validation were based on the fact that JavaScript can be turned off or HTML files can be changed.

This, however, does not apply for Android applications, or am I wrong? Is there any reason why I should be double-validating data that I consider impossible to go to the server in an unchecked form?

Comment: Just one of possible questions. Do you think your app can "live" without a CSRF protection?

Comment: well Im not very familiar with this, I read about it in wikipedia but I dont understand how this could apply in the case of an android app, can you give me an example, please

Comment: If I understand correctly you have not only the app but a backend server. Without CSRF protection anyone can intercept traffic from your app and simulate a request from your app.

Comment: cant I limit the access to the server to come only from the app?

Comment: How do you suppose to distinguish your app from a fake which prentend to be your app? People invented CSRF for this. If you know other way, please share it.

Comment: ...ment CSRF token. It's generated and validated server-side.